# Synchronisation issue. Corrupted ItemSyncTimestamps

Tags: synchronization, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

Here is the thing - We have following sequence of product CatalogVersions: **Default:Staged** -> **AA:Staged** -> **AA:Online**.

So it means **AA:Online** pulls products from **AA:Staged** and in its turn **AA:Staged** pulls from **Default:Staged**.

To make it possible there are two sync jobs **Default:Staged -> AA:Staged** and **AA:Staged -> AA:Online**

We face with quite strange behaviour of **AA:Staged -> AA:Online** sync job - during synchronisation it creates new ItemSyncTimestamps where **Source item** is a product from **Default:Staged** but not from expected one - **AA:Staged**.

Also there are ItemSyncTimestamps which has as **Source item** and **Target item** same product from **AA:Online**, so it syncs with it self.

No exceptions in log during ItemSyncTimestamp creation time or item sync. Locally works perfect..

I will appreciate any help with solving it or just pointing direction for investigation

**Hybris version 1905.9**

Comment: Have you tried deleting the ItemSyncTimestamps and running the sync again? Does it still create incorrect ItemSyncTimestamps? Also, what minor patch/version are you using?

Comment: No I have not, since business want to figure out what is going on and why...
Hybris version - 1905.9